# How Can I Join Two DB Tables and Return Lowest Price From Joined Table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two tables, the first table has the product and the second table the prices. The price table could have more than one price per product but I only want to display the lowest. But I keep getting all the prices returned and I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it.

this is what I get returned in my query:

SELECT * FROM `products` AS pr JOIN `prices` AS p ON pr.id = p.product_id WHERE pr.live = 1 AND p.live = 1

```
id product1 name description £100
id product1 name description £300
id product1 name description £200
id product2 name description £50
id product2 name description £80
id product2 name description £60
id product3 name description £222
id product3 name description £234
id product3 name description £235
```

but I'm after:

```
id product1 name description £100
id product2 name description £50
id product3 name description £222
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Output, in turn, should be encased in `<blockquote><pre>` or (someday) `<samp>` elements. Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judicious application of grouping and [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) will achieve the desired results.

```
SELECT pr.id, pr.title, pr.name, pr.description, min(p.price)
  FROM products AS pr 
    JOIN prices AS p ON pr.id = p.product_id 
  WHERE pr.live = 1 AND p.live = 1
  GROUP BY pr.id
```

However, if the price column is a text type, it probably won't use the [collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-collation-effect.html) you want, and (e.g.) '£100' will be considered less than '£90'.

Comment: Can you help me in my question please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69005703/join-two-tables-and-extract-the-lowest-price-with-multiple-conditions-multiple

Answer (score 1):

Group by product id an aggregate min on price

```
SELECT pr.*, p.m_price
FROM `products` AS pr 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT product_id, min(price) AS m_price
    FROM `prices`
    WHERE live = 1
    GROUP BY product_id
  ) AS p 
    ON pr.id = p.product_id 
WHERE pr.live = 1
```

update: something like this `MIN( CAST( SUBSTR( price, 2 ) AS DECIMAL )` could help to get rid of the `£` char and convert to number for correct aggregation on price

Comment: @Jason. In this example you get better performance if you first group and aggregate before join. Also with other DBMS (e.g. Oracle) there are other restrictions where grouping must involve all non-aggregating columns from the select. MySQL is less strict on this but you can get unexpected results sometimes.