# Join two tables and extract the lowest price with multiple conditions (multiple sku)

Tags: mysql, select

I almost finished my system until I noticed that a product had a different sku with another supplier (I have more than 15,000 products in the table `table_prices` from 7 different suppliers, it is assumed that they all have to handle the same `SKU` (but they don't), I came up with adding `sku2` to solve, but I got into a black hole.

Now taking advantage of the fact that I can get help from you, I would like to be able to search in the table `table_prices` for the lowest price if the **sku, sku2, upc or ean matches** `table_products`, in this way I will not have a major problem if a supplier decides to put a bad `sku` since I will have more information to relate.

I leave a link with what I have working ... I look for sku of `table_products` and I get the lowest price of `table_prices`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47809f/1/0

**I hope to get $90 on product 1**

```
SELECT p.*, x.supplier AS supplier, x.price , x.quantity AS quantity 
FROM table_prices x 
JOIN 
    (SELECT sku, 
    MIN(price) price 
    FROM table_prices 
    WHERE quantity != 0 AND active = 1 
    GROUP BY sku) y 
 ON y.sku = x.sku 
AND y.price = x.price 
JOIN table_products p 
WHERE p.sku = x.sku 
ORDER BY category, price
```

Comment: Have you tested my answer yet? Does it work for you and give the result you've been trying to get? If yes, please mark my answer as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to give the desired results:

```
SELECT p.*, x.supplier AS supplier, x.price , x.quantity AS quantity 
FROM table_prices x 
JOIN table_products p ON (p.sku = x.sku OR p.sku2 = x.sku OR p.upc = x.upc OR p.ean = x.ean)
WHERE x.price = (SELECT MIN(x2.price) FROM table_prices x2 WHERE (p.sku = x2.sku OR p.sku2 = x2.sku OR p.upc = x2.upc OR p.ean = x2.ean))
ORDER BY category, price
```